# Why is Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem important?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, proof-theory, incompleteness

Given that the consistency of a system can be proven outside of the given formal system, Gödel says,

> It must be noted that proposition XI... represents no contradiction to the formalities viewpoint of Hilbert....

Why do others disagree?

Who cares whether a system cannot prove its own consistency? Why would we expect such a thing?

Is it possible that a theory without multiplication, but with some other axiom or axioms (i.e., weaker in one sense but stronger in another) could prove P consistent and itself consistent?

Comment: Are you asking who cares if a theory is consistent, or are you taking as given that the consistency of mathematical theories is important?

Comment: "Given that the consistency of a system can be proven outside of the given formal system."

This is your problem. The the proof of consistency of your theory must be from a stronger theory, but, if you are wondering whether a theory is consistent, shouldn't you be worried about using a stronger theory?

Comment: Who cares if a theory can prove itself consistent, if it can be proven using some other method?

Comment: Systems don't prove themselves undecidable. That requires metamath.

Comment: @James but Is it possible that a theory without multiplication, but with some other axiom or axioms (ie weaker in one sense but stronger in another) could prove P consistent and itself consistent?

Comment: You have to think about what a proof of consistency is: It is a claim that there is no sequence of sentences in your base language $L$, that satisfies certain conditions, and ends in $x \neq x$. So, to prove consistency, you need to be able to reason about the sentences in the language *or* be able to talk about things that have properties resembling sentences (e.g. Godel numbering). Thus, a proof of the consistency of $T$ from some $S$ requires that $S$ has the resources interpret the syntax of $T$.
Edit: This is how the Godel proof goes, consistency proofs in set theory are more involved.

Comment: @James so you are saying that godel was wrong when he wrote "it is conceivable that there exist finitary proofs that cannot be expressed in the formalism of P"?

Comment: "finitary proof" is a philosophical notion, so, it depends on precisely what you mean.

Comment: @James I thought by finitary he meant basically recursive (he wouldnt use that word because he has already used it in a technical sense) or computable. For example, he constructed a recursive function Con(c), so his proof of the second theorem  is finitary.

Comment: @James wouldn't the existence of any proof outside of P contradict what you wrote in your comment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Hilbert's program](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/) aimed at "solving" the foundational issues (form Cantor and Frege, to Russell and Brouwer) proving the *consistency* of the "main" mathematical theories, like arithmetic, real analysis and set theory.

In order to prove that, the program developed concepts and tools of metamathematics, i.e. the discipline based on mathematical logic able to study the mathematical theories as mathematical objcets themselves.

This metamathematical activity has to be "performed" into a "secure" mathematical theory: the "elementary" part of arithmetic.

This theory must supply the tools sufficient for the consistency proof of other theories.

Of course, this "gound-level" mathematical theory must be itself consistent.

Unfortunately, [Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) shows that a formalized arithmetical theory having "enough resources" (this concept is made precise by the theorem) to be suitable for the metamatheatical aims is not able to prove its own consistency, and neither the consistency of "more powerful" theories like real analysis and set theory.

---

Regarding Gödel's comment after Th.XI :

> I wish to note expressily that Theorem XI *do not contradict Hilbert's formalistic viewpoint* [emphasis added]. For this viewpoint presupposes only the existence of a consistency proof in which nothing but finitary means of proof is used, and it is conceivable that there exist finitary proofs that *cannot* be expressed in the formalism of $P$.

And this was exactly what happened with [Gentzen's consistency proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof).

Some comments are useful here :

- Hilbert's concept of *finitary* is not precise: but it's hard to escape from the expectation that the "finitary part" of arithmetic must include $\mathsf{PA}$; thus, G's Th applies.
- Gentzen's proof is hardly "finitistic".
- the original aim of Hilbert's program was to "convince" intuitionstic mathematicians that axiomatized set theory was "secure"; if so, any "ostensive" consistency proof based on a model of, e.g. arithmetic, built up into set theory was clearly useless.

---

*Added*

Regarding your added question, you can see (in general) :

- Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=-SBpYKebkJMC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed 2013).

In particular, you can see the overview of [Presburger's arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) for a (very weak) first-order theory of the natural numbers with addition, **without** multiplication.

This theory is *complete* and decidable; thus, it "eludes" G's First Th.

Unfortunately, without multiplication it has not enough resources to implement the arithmetization of syntax; thus, it is unable to "perform" the basic metamathematical tasks and so it cannot prove relevant metamathemetical properties, like *consistency* of a theory (and neither of itself).

[Gentzen's consistency proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) "eludes" in some way G's Second Th :

> Gentzen showed that the consistency of first-order arithmetic is provable, over the base theory of *primitive recursive arithmetic* with the additional principle of quantifier-free transfinite induction up to the ordinal $ε_0$.
>
> Gentzen's proof also highlights one commonly missed aspect of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem. It is sometimes claimed that the consistency of a theory can only be proved in a stronger theory. The theory obtained by adding quantifier-free transfinite induction to primitive recursive arithmetic proves the consistency of first-order arithmetic but is not stronger than first-order arithmetic.
>
> For example, it does not prove ordinary mathematical induction for all formulae, while first-order arithmetic does (it has this as an axiom schema). The resulting theory is not weaker than first-order arithmetic either, since it can prove a number-theoretical fact - the consistency of first-order arithmetic - that first-order arithmetic cannot. The two theories are simply incomparable.

Comment: I was unaware of this. My only knowledge of the second incompleteness theorem is from godels paper.

Comment: @MadScientist - I know ... the link to Stanford's entry provides you with a very useful intro to the background of G's Th.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to get back to this with proper responses. Currently dealing with a fussy baby.

Answer (score 33):

You asked in a comment:

> Who cares if a theory can prove itself consistent, if it can be proven using some other method?

Let us first observe that inconsistent theories are entirely worthless.  You want to know if $X$ is true, and then you prove that it is a consequence of theory $T$, so you now go around  believing $X$.  If you later  find that $T$ is inconsistent, then $T$ cannot lend any support whatever to $X$.  You might as well be flipping coins to decide what theorems are true.  $T$ is worthless; you will have to find some other reason to believe $X$.

So you would like to find some theory $T$ for which you have good reason to believe $T$ is consistent.  One plausible-seeming method is to choose axioms that are as simple as possible and which seem intuitively true.  But the crisis of set theory around 1905 shows that this method *does not always work*.  The comprehension axiom of naïve set theory is as simple and intuitively plausible as anything, and it is false.  The discovery that it was false precipitated the formalist programs of Hilbert and Whitehead & Russell, and was the direct motivation for Gödel's work.

So you might like a proof that theory $T$ is consistent.  Unfortunately, Gödel's theorem shows that $T$ cannot do it and neither can any theory strictly weaker than $T$.  So if you want to show that $T$ is not completely worthless, you need a theory, say $T'$, that is stronger in at least one aspect.  So suppose you show that $T$ is consistent, using $T'$.

If $T'$ is chosen to be strictly stronger than $T$, so that $T'$ shows as much as $T$ does and also shows that $T$ is consistent, then now you are in a very stupid position. If you weren't sure that $T$ was consistent, $T'$ cannot help you, because if $T$ is inconsistent, then so is $T'$.  So you didn't trust $T$, but you have even *less* reason to trust $T'$.  Suppose Shady Joe offers to sell you the Empire State Building for $5.  You are not sure, and suspect that Joe is trying to scam you.  Joe insists that he is honest, and suggests his Uncle Louie as a character witness.  So you go up to the state prison where Uncle Louie is serving a fifteen-year sentence for fraud, and, from his prison cell, Louie assures you that Shady Joe is offering you a fair deal.

But this is exactly the position we are in.  We would like to prove things about numbers, say the twin prime conjecture.  We have the Peano axioms, which we believe capture how numbers work.  But how do we know that from these axioms there is not some  proof, perhaps a very long one, that  $4923 = 4925$?  This would not show that $4923$ *actually* equals $4925$; it would only show that PA was broken.  We would have to throw away PA and use something else instead, as we did with naïve set theory.  If we knew that PA was consistent, we would know that there was no such proof.  And there is a proof of the consistency of PA using ZF set theory!  But this is like asking Uncle Louie if Shady Joe is telling the truth, because if PA is inconsistent, then so is ZFC; if PA was inconsistent, then ZFC would prove that PA was consistent *anyway*.

Comment: Is it completely impossible that a theory without multiplication, but with some other axiom or axioms (ie weaker in one sense but stronger in another) could prove it consistent and itself consistent. That is how I interpreted godel.

Comment: Dammit, so Shady Joe was scamming me all that time?! And to think I trusted Louie! >:(

Comment: Dude, you've devoted your *life* to trusting Louie.

Comment: So....Is my last comment so wrong headed that it doesn't merit a response?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it's not easy to see how  a theory could be useful for proving things about mathematics if it can't even *express* the well-known claim that $2\times 2 = 4$.

Comment: Just because I trust Louie does not mean that Shady Joe haven't sold me the Empire State building for real. Maybe he's the original owner! Maybe he's one of those descendants of the original owners of the Manhattan island.

Comment: Maybe math just needs two theories instead of one.

Comment: @MadScientist I suppose if you believe that true and false are not a strict dichotomy, then it might make sense to have multiple theories that give opposing results. Of course, at that point, you've thrown the notion of consistency out the window.

Comment: @jpmc26 they wouldn't give opposing results. One theory would simply add to the other.

Comment: @MadScientist That's the situation this answer describes, though. They aren't really two separate theories, then, either. They form a single, larger theory together. One which, as a whole, still cannot be proven to be self consistent.

Comment: Sure, trusting $T$ because $T'$ says it's consistent is not epistemologically sound, but is trusting $T$ just because it can prove itself consistent any better? Is that not some form of circular reasoning? Self-proving consistency has the advantage of being amenable to a precise mathematical definition, but that doesn't necessarily make it philosophically useful...

Comment: @JackM They Are Saying It Would Be Useful because it would Escape The regress of using another theory that is likewise possibly inconsistent.

Comment: @JackM You've misread. $T$ **cannot** prove itself consistent. It is incapable of doing so. So we're forced to accept some axioms without definitive proof; we can't do any better. That's math, science, life in general for you. We can't prove anything with total certainty. We have to accept a starting point.

Comment: @jpmc26 so you are saying that godel was wrong when he wrote "it is conceivable that there exist finitary proofs that cannot be expressed in the formalism of P"?

Comment: @MJD when you wrote " So you didn't trust T, but you have evenless reason to trust T'"  are saying that godel was wrong when he wrote "it is conceivable that there exist finitary proofs that cannot be expressed in the formalism of P"?

Comment: @MJD From Mauro ' s link to the wiki on Gentzen's proof in the Answer below I Found this: "Gentzen's proof also highlights one commonly missed aspect of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem. It is sometimes claimed that the consistency of a theory can only be proved in a stronger theory. The theory obtained by adding quantifier-free transfinite induction to primitive recursive arithmetic proves the consistency of first-order arithmetic but is not stronger than first-order arithmetic." This seems to contradict your answer. Does it not?

Comment: @MadScientist I'm just trying to clarify this answer. If I understand that quote correctly, it's saying that there may be higher order theories beyond $P$ that can show the consistency of $P$. The second incompleteness theorem says that any attempt of a theory proving *itself* consistent makes the theory inconsistent, not that higher order theories can't. I mean that when you accept a higher order theory, you now just have a different set of axioms. I can't imagine how theories could be so fundamentally segregated that they can't be treated as a single theory, but perhaps I'm just uninformed.

Comment: @MJD although your answer has the most votes it seems wrong given what ive read in this wikipedia article. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof

Comment: @MadScientist: I know this is very late, but your last comment is right, but then again are you saying you would suspect PA of being inconsistent while you wouldn't suspect $ε_0$ of being not well-ordered? =) Anyway, your first comment is also probably right; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-verifying_theories.

Comment: On this topic, logician [Jean-Yves Girard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Yves_Girard) says: “A consistency proof is like an insurance [policy] against an explosion of [the] Earth”: useless because if the Earth is destroyed, you never get to collect your insurance settlement.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your last comment:

> "Who cares if a theory can prove itself consistent, if it can be
>   proven using some other method? "

It's not that we can prove it using some other *method*, but we can prove it using some other (stronger) theory. But how can we prove that this stronger theory is consistent? (if this stronger theory itself is not consistent, it means that our proof does not amount to much as nobody assures as that it's result are indeed true)

So now we want to prove the consistency of this stronger theory. But we need another theory for that! A stronger one! And how do we prove the consistency of the latter?

You see where we are heading? You can make the exact same reasoning for ever, so proving the consistency of a theory using another one doesn't do much because then we can't prove the consistency of the latter, and we are doomed

Comment: Did Godel himself not appreciate this point when he wrote that it "represents no contradiction to the formalistic standpoint of hilbert. For this presupposes only the existence of a consistency proof effected by finite means  and there might be finite proofs that are not in p. " isn't it possible that the consistency proof of p could be in a system that is weaker than p (in the sense that it doesn't include multiplication for example,  but perhaps something else?)

Comment: @MadScientist If you can prove something with a system weaker that $p$, then you can prove it with $p$ itself - isn't that what "weaker" means?